# Why does IProxyService.select(URI) return IProxyData[]?

Tags: java, network-programming, eclipse-rcp

I would expect it to return just `IProxyData` (`null` if no proxy should be used). Can it return an array with more than 1 element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can define as many set of proxies that you want.
Eclipse has three:

- manual
- direct
- native

Each three have their own `http.proxy`, `https.proxy`, `ftp.proxy` settings.

See as an example "[Re-using the Eclipse proxy preference settings in your Eclipse RCP application](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/12/08/eclipse-rcp-proxy-preference/)" (by [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.de/about.html))

[image]

Comment: I thought only one of these sets is active at any time ("Active Provider: Native" on your screenshot). Notably, the first comment there says "I usually just pick the first element of the array (if there is one), but I also have never seen more than one proxy data returned by select."

Comment: @Alexey: as Eclipse uses those connections, yes, only one is active at any given time. But that doesn't mean your system has only one proxy connection active.

Comment: So, how can I find which is the active provider?

Comment: @Alexey: if it returns only one element, that is the active provider (which is the default behavior in Eclipse, where you have only one provider active at a time)